# Filter on one2many_list widget and context passing

Tags: odoo

I have 2 one2many fields that are represented by one2many_list widget. The fields are:

> ```
> documents_applicant_1 = fields.One2many(comodel_name='application.documents',
> documents_applicant_2 = fields.One2many(comodel_name='application.documents',
>                                         inverse_name='application_id')
> ```

```
                            <group>
                                <field name="documents_applicant_1" widget="one2many_list"
                                    nolabel="1">
                                    <tree string="Variants" editable="bottom">
                                        <field name="name" />
                                        <field name="document_raw_data" id="document_raw_data_applicant_1" />
                                        <!-- <field name="category" /> -->
                                    </tree>
                                </field>
                            </group>
                            <group>
                                <field name="documents_applicant_2" widget="one2many_list"
                                    nolabel="1">
                                    <tree string="Variants" editable="bottom">
                                        <field name="name" />
                                        <field name="document_raw_data" id="document_raw_data_applicant_2" />
                                        <!-- <field name="category" /> -->
                                    </tree>
                                </field>
                            </group>
```

When the user adds records using those fields, depending on the list he uses to add a record, I want to pass a context. My layout is the following:

[image]

Now besides wanting to pass a different context when my user adds records to the left list and the right one, I want to apply a dynamic filter on the records shown on both the lists.

How can the above be achieved?
I do not wish to write javascript rather than use existing funtionality

Answer (score 1):

You can add the domain you want to the `One2many` fields in Python code (in XML that is not going to work). And then, in XML, you can add the context using the prefix `default_`.

> I put you an example:
>
> Suppose you want `documents_applicant_1` field for adding records
>   whose category is *'A'*, and `documents_applicant_2` field for adding
>   records whose category is *'B'*.
>
> Then you can write:
>
> **Python code**
>
> ```
> documents_applicant_1 = fields.One2many(
>     comodel_name='application.documents',
>     inverse_name='application_id',
>     domain=[('category' '=', 'A')],
> )
> documents_applicant_2 = fields.One2many(
>     comodel_name='application.documents',
>     inverse_name='application_id',
>     domain=[('category' '=', 'B')],
> )
> ```
>
> **XML code**
>
> ```
> <group>
>     <field name="documents_applicant_1" widget="one2many_list"
>         nolabel="1" context={'default_category': 'A', }>
>         <tree string="Variants" editable="bottom">
>             <field name="name" />
>             <field name="document_raw_data" id="document_raw_data_applicant_1" />
>             <field name="category" />
>         </tree>
>     </field>
> </group>
> <group>
>     <field name="documents_applicant_2" widget="one2many_list"
>         nolabel="1" context={'default_category': 'B', }>
>         <tree string="Variants" editable="bottom">
>             <field name="name" />
>             <field name="document_raw_data" id="document_raw_data_applicant_2" />
>             <field name="category" />
>         </tree>
>     </field>
> </group>
> ```

I do not know if this is what you were looking for, I hope it helps you.